# Number of sequences $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$ such that: $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq ... \subseteq A_k = [n]$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

For given numbers $n, k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ find the number of sequences $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$ such that: $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq ... \subseteq A_k = [n]$

$[n] = \{1,2,3 ... n \}$

I know that A_k needs to contain all [n]. Then every other set must be a subset of that one. So we van choose $A_{k-1}$ in one of $\sum_{i=0}^n {{n}\choose{i}}$ ways. But then, for each of those we are faced with the same problem and I don't see how it can be described as dependent on n since some of those subsets in the sequence can be equal to one another.

Comment: Please explain the notation $[n]$ (I can guess, but I would rather not).

Comment: Also, one is given $a$, but then it vanishes from the problem statement. On the other hand $n$ is not present in the problem statement, and yet it has not been given. Perhaps $a=n$?

Comment: I'm sorry, all edited.

Comment: Hint using some small cases: For $k = 2$, this is simple: you need to make $A_1$ some subset of $[n],$ so you have $2^n$ options. For $k = 3,$ suppose I tell you a choice of $A_{2}$. Then the number of choices of $A_1$ is the same as the case $k=2$, that is, $2^{|A_2|}$ (why?). Since you can pick an $A_2$ of size $j$ in $\binom{n}{j}$ ways, this let's you compute the answer for the case $k = 3$. a) What is this answer? b) Does anything prevent this argument from extending to $k = 4$? c) Can you now answer the general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associated to any nested sequence $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq A_k=[n]$ there is a function $f : [n] \to [k]$ which is defined as follows: for each $i \in [n]$, $f(i)$ is the least value of $j \in [k]$ such that $i \in A_j$. Intuitively, the element $i$ is "born" on day $j$.

Also, associated to any function $f : [n] \to [k]$ there is a corresponding nested sequence $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq A_k=[n]$ which is defined as follows: for each $j=1,...,k$ the set $A_j$ is defined as all $i \in [n]$ such that $f(i) \le j$. Intuitively, $A_j$ is all elements "born" on or before day $j$.

These two operations (from nested sequences of subsets to functions; and from functions to nested sequences of subsets) are inverses of each other. So the number of such sequences equals the number of such functions, and the latter number is $k^n$.